# How to develop a layer that works with arbitrary size input

Tags: keras

I'm trying to develop a layer in Keras which works with 3D tensors. To make it flexible, I would like to postpone the code that relies on the input's exact shape as much as possible.

My layer is overriding 5 methods:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, inputs, verbose=False):
        second_dim = K.int_shape(inputs)[-2]
        # Do something with the second_dim

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def get_config(self):
        pass
```

And I'm using this layer like this:

```
input = Input(batch_shape=(None, None, 128), name='input')
x = MyLayer(name='my_layer')(input)
model = Model(input, x)
```

But I'm facing an error since the `second_dim` is `None`. How can I develop a layer that relies on the dimensions of the input but it's ok with it being provided by the actual data and not the input layer?

Comment: Not an expert on costum layers, but I think you need to add 
`super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)`
and 
`super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape) `

to `__init__` and `build`, respectively.

Might be worth a try.

Comment: @Lafayette Thanks but this is only a schema and not the actual code. I do have them in my code I just didn't want to make the post long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the same question differently, and I've got a perfect answer:

[What is the right way to manipulate the shape of a tensor when there are unknown elements in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303778/what-is-the-right-way-to-manipulate-the-shape-of-a-tensor-when-there-are-unknown)

The gist of it is, don't treat the dimensions directly. Use them by reference and not by value. So, do not use `K.int_shape` and instead use `K.shape`. And use Keras operations to compose and come up with a new shape:

```
shape = K.shape(x)
newShape = K.concatenate([
                             shape[0:1], 
                             shape[1:2] * shape[2:3],
                             shape[3:4]
                         ])
```