# What is the right way to manipulate the shape of a tensor when there are unknown elements in it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say that I have a tensor of shape `(None, None, None, 32)` and I want to reshape this to `(None, None, 32)` where the middle dimension is the product of two middle dimensions of the original one. What is the right way to do so?

Comment: Doesn't flatten do the trick ?

Comment: I'm not sure how. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, that was a little dry ;) I think you can try the `tf.compat.v1.layers.flatten` layer. It should do the trick !

Comment: I'm not 100% sure though, so you may want to check its behavior with a tensor of known dimensions,

Comment: @JosephBudin: Keep in mind that he wants a product as middle dimension. So I'd rathe create a new tensor with your desired calculation and the right dimensions (if your memory allows this).

Comment: @JosephBudin :) I understood your comment but I don't see how flatten could do the trick. It will return a 1D tensor. I don't see how is that going to be changed into a 3D tensor the way I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I meant the `tf.contrib.layers.flatten` layer. It's used in image classification for instance in order to pass from convolutional-friendly features to fully-connected ones

Comment: @JosephBudin thanks but this question is not about using layers. It's about developing a layer. This is used within a layer. Flatten is definitely not going to work.

Comment: You can use layers inside layers, what would be wrong in this ? Maybe we don't have the same definition of layer in mind.

Comment: You are right, you can use layers inside another layer. But that's overkill. You usually use backend functions. Flatten for instance uses `reshape` underneath. You are much better off just calling that function directly. But still, that's not going to help here. The problem is not the function to call but instead, the parameters to call it with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import keras.backend as K

def flatten_pixels(x):
    shape = K.shape(x)
    newShape = K.concatenate([
                                 shape[0:1], 
                                 shape[1:2] * shape[2:3],
                                 shape[3:4]
                             ])

    return K.reshape(x, newShape)
```

Use it in a `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

model.add(Lambda(flatten_pixels))
```

---

A little knowledge:

- `K.shape` returns the "current" shape of the tensor, containing data - It's a `Tensor` containing `int` values for all dimensions. It only exists properly when running the model and can't be used in model definition, only in runtime calculations.
- `K.int_shape` returns the "definition" shape of the tensor as a `tuple`. This means the variable dimensions will come containing `None` values.

Comment: Thanks, the use of `concatenate` and also `shape[0:1]` instead of `shape[0]` did the trick. Awesome.

Comment: Following up on my question, what if I need to use the `/` operator? I mean `*` between two int32 will result in `int32` (not considering overflow). But if I need to say `shape[1:2] / shape[2:3]`, this will result in `float64`. I'm doing that right now and the Tensorflow is complaining that all the dimentions need to be `int32`. Do you have a recipe for that too?

Comment: There is always a `K.cast(...)` if you need. :)